# NetworkManager keeps reconnecting and chaning IP address, Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: networking, wireless

In certain wifi networks my laptop keeps reconnecting in seemingly random intervals, anytime between 1-60 minutes. In logs I am finding messages such as following:

```
wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-76 noise=9999 txrate=26000
NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913817.0277] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=10.13.2.61
```

Why is the system deciding to drop the wifi connection? Is it because of signal strength, as indicated above (signal=-76), or is that unrelated?

It is a problem because after reconnecting to the wifi, the system obtains a new IP address, which makes all existing ssh connections freeze.

In more detail, logs from the initial connection:

```
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911934.3419] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911934.3420] device (wlp1s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "eduroam"
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911934.3420] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911934.3422] device (wlp1s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-58 noise=9999 txrate=26000
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911934.3462] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv6 with address fe80::33e0:44c4:f396:7975.
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: New relevant interface wlp1s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr 19 15:45:34 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Registering new address record for fe80::33e0:44c4:f396:7975 on wlp1s0.*.
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4593] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=10.13.0.162
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv4 with address 10.13.0.162.
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: New relevant interface wlp1s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Registering new address record for 10.13.0.162 on wlp1s0.IPv4.
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4633] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4651] device (wlp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4652] device (wlp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4656] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4666] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4667] policy: set 'eduroam' (wlp1s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4669] device (wlp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4671] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 19 15:45:35 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681911935.4673] manager: startup complete
```

And Wifi reconnecting here with a new IP address obtained:

```
Apr 19 16:15:03 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-61 noise=9999 txrate=130000
Apr 19 16:15:39 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Apr 19 16:15:39 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=21 -> NAK
Apr 19 16:15:39 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
Apr 19 16:15:39 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf 0
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 5c:83:8f:3c:8b:f0 0
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 0
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 0
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913740.2369] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> 4way_handshake
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913740.2370] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> 4way_handshake
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913740.3235] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 19 16:15:40 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913740.3257] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: Rekeying PTK for STA 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 but driver can't safely do that.
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: deauthenticated from 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 (Reason: 15=4WAY_HANDSHAKE_TIMEOUT)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-9999 noise=9999 txrate=0
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 reason=15
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: BSSID 00:a7:42:b9:cf:c0 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.4085] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.4086] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.4849] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.4850] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf 0
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 5c:83:8f:3c:8b:f0 0
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf (SSID='eduroam' freq=5320 MHz)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: authenticate with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.6487] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.6487] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: send auth to 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf (try 1/3)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: Trying to associate with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf (SSID='eduroam' freq=5320 MHz)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: authenticated
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: associate with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf (try 1/3)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.6812] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.6813] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf (capab=0x111 status=0 aid=2)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: Associated with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: associated
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7255] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7256] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7256] device (wlp1s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7575] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7576] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7576] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed no lease
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913743.7577] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=21 -> NAK
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
Apr 19 16:15:43 xlap kernel: wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 17 dBm as advertised by 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: EAP-TLV: TLV Result - Success - EAP-TLV/Phase2 Completed
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-REMOVED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf 0
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf 0
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:a7:42:b9:cf:cf completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913744.3398] device (wlp1s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap wpa_supplicant[1179]: wlp1s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=-76 noise=9999 txrate=26000
Apr 19 16:15:44 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913744.3407] device (p2p-dev-wlp1s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap NetworkManager[1177]: <info>  [1681913749.4690] dhcp4 (wlp1s0): state changed new lease, address=10.13.3.14
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Withdrawing address record for 10.13.0.162 on wlp1s0.
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv4 with address 10.13.0.162.
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Interface wlp1s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp1s0.IPv4 with address 10.13.3.14.
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: New relevant interface wlp1s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 19 16:15:49 xlap avahi-daemon[1119]: Registering new address record for 10.13.3.14 on wlp1s0.IPv4.
```

Comment: First, that's the expected `ssh` response. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator Of course I understand that the ssh connection freezes when the laptop obtains a new IP address. My question is why the laptop loozes wifi connection, in logs there is nothing to indicate the reason other than the lines I showed above.

Comment: I also faced the same issue . Earlier i was using ubuntu 20.04 which was working fine and now upgraded to 22.04.02 LTS which keep reconnecting to WiFI and IP getting changed each time . It looks like Ubuntu 22 release the dhcp lease very frequently. @petr let me know if you found the any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a [bug in NetworkManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/1404).

If that bug is triggered by your client switching between 5GHz and 2.4GHz on a single access point, then you can work around this by forcing the use of a particular band: (Use "a" for 5GHz or "bg" for 2.4GHz)

`nmcli connection modify <SSID> 802-11-wireless.band a`

If that bug is triggered by roaming between access points, then you might be able to work around this by switching from NetworkManager's internal DHCP client to an external DHCP client ([using the main/dhcp setting in NetworkManager](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html)).

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.