# Wifi symbol shows connected but every couple of minutes I lose connection to the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, mediatek

I have a Lenovo Laptop and am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. My kernel version is 6.5.0-15-generic. The wifi driver being used is mt7921e. I am connected to the internet through wifi. But every 15-20 minutes, my internet stops working. The websites lose internet connection and the wifi icon shows a question mark. But after about 30 seconds evrything gets back to normal. This a regular recurring issue and I have tried most of the available solutions I could find on the internet. The following lines of code helps temporarily but the issue comes back after a while -

```
sudo modprobe -r mt7921e
sudo modprobe mt7921e
```

I am really frustrated about this because I mostly work remotely and a stable internet connection is a must for me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit : Here's the required information in pastebin :

[Pastebin - Results from wireless script](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GdGJHD3RNy/)

Edit (2) : Here's the termbin link for generated info from the script when internet went down again -

https://termbin.com/j7i3

Edit (3) : Here's the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` -

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8ktH2m8gPc/

And here's the output from `service NetworkManager status` -

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/vHFjqDhKCC/

Here's the output from `service --status-all` -

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/k6CvRY4xVS/

Comment: Does this happen at multiple physical locations?  Have you checked kernel messages using `dmesg`?  Have you checked for system messages in various /var/log files?  See which files are the newest using `ls -lt /var/log |head`, then examine those.  You can check for messages from systemd-related components using `journalctl -r` ("-r" reverse date order).

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the question to include results from the wireless script

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: @klode I have noticed that everytime I am losing internet connection this is shown in dmesg -

*systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.*

Comment: @Jeremy31 Edited as requested

Comment: Wait until wifi fails then run `./wireless-info` then fix it and run `cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999` and post termbin.com URL

Comment: @Jeremy31 Edited the main post and added the url as requested.

Comment: @waltinator i am seeing this message logged every time the issue occurs

*dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed new lease*

Comment: Someone else is going through the same issue as mine I think 

See - [NetworkManager keeps reconnecting and chaning IP address, Ubuntu 22.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464265/networkmanager-keeps-reconnecting-and-chaning-ip-address-ubuntu-22-04-2)

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and show us the WiFi messages covering the whole transaction. Simply showing a single error without context doesn't help us help you. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: @waltinator I have edited the post with pastebin links containing the required infromations

Comment: sorry for pinging @waltinator but anything you can suggest? I am still facing the issue

Comment: It looks like your DHCP server (the one you're connecting to) issues IP Addresses with very short lease times. In addition, have you read the answer to your "same as" reference?  Do you have IPv6 enabled? Do you need it?

Comment: @waltinator Yes I have read the answers to the mentioned reference and have followed the solution mentioned, but it didn't solve the issue for me. And I have disabled IPV6 from wifi settings as I do not need it. Even when writing this message I lost connection once. This is extremely frustrating and I know it's not an issue related to the router settings since everything works fine on windows on the same device

Comment: @Jeremy31 you got any more suggestion?

Comment: I have done a complete reinstallation of ubuntu and the problem persists. I think the problem is indeed with ubuntu